# Angular 4 get [routerLink] ViewChildren

Tags: angular, routerlink, viewchild

I'm trying to get a list of all links in my current component, with a template looking something along the lines of this:

```
<div *ngFor="let link of links">
  <a [routerLink]="[link.url]">{{ link.label }}</a>
</div>
```

I tried to set up an `@ViewChildren(RouterLink) links: QueryList<RouterLink>;`. This list was always empty though.

A quick experiment with `@ViewChild(RouterLink) elem: RouterLink;`:

```
<div [routerLink]="[]">Bla</div>
```

returns a value, while

```
<a [routerLink]="[]">Bla</a>
```

does not.

I checked in the documentation: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink, where the selector is actually given as `:not(a)[routerLink]`, so the experiment makes sense.

Now is the question: How do I get a list of `[routerLink]` that are an attribute of an `<a>` element? I couldn't find any `AComponent` or something suspicious.

A possible fallback would be, to add an ID on all elements `<a #myLink [routerLink]="[]">`, but that seems kind of weird, since I already have an identifying criterion I'd like to use.

How can I find my list of `[routerLink]`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing when i saw there was a
`RouterLinkWithHref`.
I didn't have time to try it, but I suppose it can help you.

If I have the time latter, I'll try it and edit my answer.

## [EDIT]

I tried and indeed, both (with and without a `a`) works.

It's all supposition but they might have created `RouterLinkWithHref` to interact with existing anchor mechanism (useful for SEO).

Then making the directive for none anchor tags seems logical (overlaping a component selector and a directive selector doesn't feel right).

Anyway, I didn't found any solution to get `RouterLink` and `RouterLinkWithHref` in a single ViewChildren.

Comment: I just tried,  it's strange that we can't select by routerLink when it's on a <a> but with the RouterLinkWithHref selector it work : @ViewChildren(RouterLinkWithHref) elem: QueryList<RouterLinkWithHref>;

and keep you html like this seem to work ;)